# Generating pseudo-random numbers by window-sampling from a set (with mutations)

Tags: random-generation

Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician not a statistician.

Here's a problem I am trying to solve:
For a specific programming task which relies on sequences of pseudo-random integers I have come up with an approach which provides significant speed boost.

Let me describe some details:
I need a vector V of W pseudo-random integers (each integer in a range 0-MAX).
Instead of generating its contents each time this vector has to be used in calculations, I have another larger vector P of Q pseudo random integers that was initially populated.
To obtain vector V I randomly select window of size W from vector P.

This alone is not sufficient, so I have introduced *mutation* of vector P. This *mutation* is executed after each selection of window from vector P and involves replacing M numbers from vector P with new pseudo-random integers.
This *mutation* step has provided noticeable improvement in *randomness* of numbers window-sampled from vector P.

There is a question, however, which I don't know the answer to and I do not quite how to tackle, except maybe by running some empirical experiments.

The question is, how many numbers in vector P need to be replaced with new values each time a window is selected to form vector V, so that randomness of values in vector V is sufficient (with a confidence level).
I would assume that number of such individual mutations will depend on W (size of vector V), Q (size of vector P), range of integers' values (MAX).

Is there a formula that approximates required number M of such mutations, given a confidence level stating that numbers in vector V are as random as *freshly* generated, e.g. M(W, Q, MAX, 95%) = ?

I have an alternative problem that is similar, in which pseudo-random numbers are 0s and 1s, and vector P has a fixed proportion between occurences of 0s and 1s, and the single mutation operation involves swapping two randomly selected items in vector P.

Thank you, any hints will be appreciated (even properly naming phenomena I've described, so I could try to search for answers effectively on my own).